# Django template not executing Jquery click

Tags: jquery, django

I'm using Django 1.5.  After reading dozens of posts here, I'm still baffled why the click event is not fired.

HTML template (section):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"
             method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>File accepted & ready to process: <b>{{ file }}</b> </p>
    <br><p><button id="process">Process</button></p>
    <br><br>
    {% if task_id %}
        <p>Processing record: </p>
        <div id="record">{{ record }} of </div>
        <div id="total">{{ total }}</div>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Relevant script:

```
<script>
$('#process').click(function() {
    $.post({
        url: "do_task",
        data: {},
        success: function() {
            $.post({
                url: "/main/",
                context: document.body,
                success: function(s, x) {
                    $(this).html(s);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

What am I missing or having it wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors on your javascript console?

Comment: Jquery is loaded, right?

Comment: I faced same type of problem sometime back. It was solved by adding type="button" inside the button element. It might look strange but it worked for me.

Comment: @user2707389, Jquery is indeed loaded, actually, all other scripts are working fine.

Comment: @anuragal, tried your suggestion of adding the type but no change either.  What else can I try?

Comment: Tried using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5epy/1/), click event working perfect.

Comment: Thanks anuragal.  You are right: the click event was in fact working.  I realized last night that the real problem was the order and types of argument on the jquery shortcut POST for $.ajax was incorrect.  Explained in detail in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event was indeed working.  What was not working is the action within the fucntion, since I was using the wrong set of arguments.

Originally, the arguments url: URL, data: data, success: function is for the $.ajax method.  But instead, I was using $.post, which the method with its arguments is as follows:

$.post(URL, data, function(data), dataType)

Note: function(data) is the callback function to be called as a successful request.  The data, callback function and dataType are optional.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#process').click(function() {
        $.post({
            url: "do_task",
            data: {},
            success: function() {
                $.post({
                    url: "/main/",
                    context: document.body,
                    success: function(s, x) {
                        $(this).html(s);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: That's the way it was originally written.  Anyway, I did it again but no change.